# Preview link leads to the old version of the resume in the resume uploader

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

The resume uploader doesn't provide the right preview link.  To reproduce:

- Go to a job posting
- Click on apply now
- Submit cover letter
- In resume portion, click "attach new resume" (Skip this step if a resume was previously uploaded for another posting)
- Hard refresh the page
- Navigate back to the resume uploader
- Click the X to remove the old resume
- Attach a different resume
- Click the filename, the old resume will download

However, the file is indeed uploaded; hard-refreshing the page again and navigating to the same submission step will show the properly uploaded file.

Comment: This seems to be working now.